# accordion does not not retract the open section when opening another in bootstrap-4

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, bootstrap-4

I am working with bootstrap-4 and laravel 5.5, I have made a dynamic accordion, but I have a problem, when I open a card through the link the content is displayed, but when opening another, the one that I opened previously should be closed but not does, only the event is made correctly when I open the first card and then I open another card, the first card is retracted and the current card remains open, I do not know if I have been clear

```
@foreach($users as $user)   
            <div id="accordion">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header" id="heading{{$user->id}}">
                      <h5 class="mb-0">
                        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{$user->id}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="{{$user->id}}">
                           {{$user->name}}
                        </button>
                      </h5>
                    </div> 
                    {{-- el loop->index me devuelve el indice del ciclo en el que estoy --}}
                     <div id="{{$user->id}}" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading{{$user->id}}" data-parent="#accordion">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                              <li class="list-group-item">id: {{$user->id}}</li>
                              <li class="list-group-item">email: {{$user->email}}</li>
                              @if ($user->type == 'admin')
                                   <li class="list-group-item">Rol: {{$user->type}}  <i class="fa fa-user-secret"></i></li>
                              @elseif($user->type =='supervisor')
                                   <li class="list-group-item">Rol: {{$user->type}}  <i class="fa fa-binoculars"></i></li>
                              @else
                                   <li class="list-group-item">Rol: {{$user->type}}  <i class="fa fa-building"></i></li>       
                              @endif
                              <li class="list-group-item">Rol: {{$user->type}}</li>
                              <li class="list-group-item">Telefono: {{$user->telefono}}</li>
                              <li class="list-group-item">
                                    <a href="{{route('users.edit',$user->id)}}" class="btn btn-outline-dark" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Editar"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                                    <a href="{{route('admin.users.destroy',$user->id)}}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Eliminar" onclick="return confirm('¿Estas seguro de eliminar este usuario?')" class="btn btn-outline-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        @endforeach
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LaS5.png)

Comment: Please post in English so users can better understand your issue. :)

Comment: Please use English - if you are not confident, please use [es.stackoverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) - Por favor use inglés - si no tiene confianza, por favor use [es.stackoverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) (Google translate, so sorry if wrong!)